# Angular2 Trying to use localStorage globally but does not work?

Tags: angular, service, local-storage

Hi I am using localStorage in Angular2.

To check if the user is logged in, I tried to call this

```
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```

in every component but since this should be called in every component,

I decided to make it global so I created service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '../../model/auth_user';

import { HttpClient } from '../HttpClient';


@Injectable()
export class LoginCheckService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

LoginCheck(currentUser: User) {
    currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')); //to check if the user is logged in
    if (currentUser == null) {
        console.log('hello!') //just to check if the currentUser is null the 'get' method gets called, however, hello! is printed but i can't seem to track any request done. 
        this.http.get('/front/member/session');
        }
    }
}
```

Like this and in main component, I did this.

```
  currentUser: User;

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private loginCheck: LoginCheckService) {
    this.loginCheck.LoginCheck(this.currentUser);
  }
```

However, even when I am logged in, the currentUser from the main component still seems to be empty which did not happen previously when I wasnt using service.

And I also added if statement so if the currentUser is null I have to send 'get' http request but this is also not requested.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

(I added service to provider)

Comment: Try to return `currentUser` from  `LoginCheck` function and then assign it to component's local variable `currentUser`

Comment: In your service LoginCheck, why do you need the currentUser parameter? You aren't using it. In the next line you set it with the localStorage.getItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are missing a lot of code.

In your service, you made a function with a `currentUser`. Then, immediately, you change its value to your localStorage value (`currentUser = JSON.parse(...)`).

This is all you do. You should add some more code so that it does some more.

For instance :

**component**

```
constructor(/* imports */) {
    this.currentUser = this.loginCheck.LoginCheck();
}
```

**service**

```
LoginCheck(): any {
    return JSON.parse(/* your localStorage value */);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a place in your code where you are setting anything to your localStorage *currentUser* parameter.

Does your HttpClient.get returnes an Observable? If so you need to subscribe in order to initiate http request.

```
this.http.get('/front/member/session').subscribe(result => {
    // do something with result
    // save it to localstorage, i guess
});
```